# Axios demora para consumir a API?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, api, axios

Olá, galera! tudo bom?

Estou iniciando meus estudos em Vanilla Javascript para futuramente estudar frameworks que utilizem js.

Fiz um pequeno projeto web no qual o usuário digita o CEP da residencia e a aplicação utiliza o Axios para consumir uma api que retorna os dados do cep(bairro,rua,cidade...)

Porém, percebi que no primeiro clique no botão de busca, o retorno é "undefined" e, após clicar novamente, o resultado correto é apresentado na tela. Penso eu que possa ser uma "demora" para o retorno dos dados.

Segue o meu código:

(OBS: Modelo MVC)

Classe CEP:

```
 class Cep {

   constructor(){

        this.cidade;
        this.bairro;
        this.rua;
   }

   getRua(){

        return this.rua;
   }

   getBairro(){

        return this.bairro;
   }

   getCidade(){

        return this.cidade;
   }


   setEndereco(cidade,bairro,rua){

    this.cidade = cidade;
    this.bairro = bairro;
    this.rua = rua;
   }

}
```

Classe VIEW (renderiza o html na tela)

```
class View{

constructor(dom){

    this.dom = dom;
}


template(modelo){

    return `
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered mt-5">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Cidade</th>
            <th>Bairro</th>
            <th>Rua</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>


        <tr>
            <td>${modelo.getCidade()}</td>
            <td>${modelo.getBairro()}</td>
            <td>${modelo.getRua()}</td>               
        </tr>


    </tbody>
    `
}

update(modelo){

    this.dom.innerHTML = this.template(modelo);
}
```

}

Por fim, a classe Controller

```
 class CepController{

    constructor(){

        this.dom = document.querySelector('#cep');
        this.tabela = document.querySelector('#enderecos');
        this.url = 'http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/';
        this.objCep = new Cep();
        this.view = new View(this.tabela);
    }

    render(){

        axios.get(this.api_url(this.dom.value)).then((resposta)=>{

            this.objCep.setEndereco(resposta.data.cidade,resposta.data.bairro,resposta.data.logradouro);
        });       

        console.log(this.objCep);

        this.view.update(this.objCep);

        console.log(this.objCep);


        event.preventDefault();
    }

    api_url(cep){

        let retorno = this.url + cep;
        return retorno;
    }


}
```

OBS: peço desculpas se minha dúvida é muito trivial. Procurei bastante e realmente não encontrei respostas para meu problema :(

Answer (score 3):

Você não está esperando a resposta da requisição chegar antes de tentar mostrar os dados. Tente assim:

```
axios.get(this.api_url(this.dom.value)).then((resposta)=>{ 
    this.objCep.setEndereco(resposta.data.cidade, resposta.data.bairro, resposta.data.logradouro)
    this.view.update(this.objCep);
});
```